# Error handling for request using toast events in salesforce

Tags: error-handling, salesforce, toast, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I am trying to build a lwc which reads a request which has status code on it. Based on the status code there are different scenarios to show toast events. What is the best to carry out this? If it’s a 200 then skip to next lwc or next page of flow.

Any recommendations or reference for such scenarios?